# Trigger file_get_html on click using dynamic url each time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

On my page I have a list of users. Each user has a profile page on an external site (not the same domain name). To save my client updating their profile details in 2 places, I am using [PHP simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). This gets the content of the users external profile page and returns it on my site.

What I am trying to do is load the users profile information into a div on my site only when the users name is clicked.

Each user looks like this:

```
<div class="actor_container" data-url="www.external-profile-url.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
</div>
```

To get the contents of the external page I use this code:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.spotlight.com/5094-1276-6177');
echo $html->find('div.credits', 0);
```

Obviously this works at the minute as it is hard coded. However I need to make it dynamic so that the external profile info for each user is loaded when the relevant user is clicked.

**Update from answer below:**

I added this script to the top of the user list:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(".actor_container").load(function () {
    return "http://79.170.44.105/samskirrow.com/nial/wp-content/plugins/nial-customizations/front-end/my.php?url=" + $(this).data("url");
  });
});
</script>
```

then in **my.php**

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html($_GET["url"]);
echo $html->find('div.credits', 0);
```

Currently, when I click on a user, nothing happens

**UPDATE**

OK I've moved to using AJAX to access my.php. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $('.nial_actor').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://79.170.44.105/samskirrow.com/nial/wp-content/plugins/nial-customizations/front-end/my.php?url=" + $(this).data("url"),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
               var data = $.parseHTML(res); 
               // append all data
               $('#all_data').append(data);
            }
        });
      }); //on
    }); // ready

    </script>
```

However this returns the following error:

```
GET http://79.170.44.105/samskirrow.com/nial/wp-content/plugins/nial-customizations/front-end/my.php?url=undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

So for some reason the url in data-url is not adding to the end of my ajax url. Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works?

```js
$(function () {
  $(".actor_container").load(function () {
    return "my.php?url=" + $(this).data("url");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="actor_container" data-url="www.external-profile-url.com">
  <img src="...actor profile img..." />
</div>
```

And in the PHP file, you can add `url` as your `GET` param:

```
$html = file_get_html($_GET["url"]);
```

> Note that there are lots of vulnerabilities in this methods. Keep this just as a guidance.

Comment: This doesn't do anything yet. I added the js script above the list of users. And I added the full url to my.php. I added to my question using actual links. Also on my.php I added the line echo $html->find('div.credits', 0);